# Which People Picker property is being used to update SharePoint User/Group column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx

I am trying to update the value of a Person / Group column, based on an input I am receiving from Office UI Fabric People Picker, but seem unable to do so.

As per my research the property I should be using must be the User .Key, or the .Id, but none of them seem to work. I also tried with DisplayText and Login name, but that didn't work out either.

Error message observed: An internal error 'ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer_ReadPropertyValue' occurred."

Comment: Can you share the necessary code snippet related to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

In order for the update operation to succeed,

1) The correct property to be used is the Id;
2) An Id needs to be added to the column name in the JSON object we are posting as well:

example:

```
    let managerId = this.state.Manager.User.Id;

    let addMetaDataOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions =  {
    body: `{
      "Title": "Projectmetadata",
      "projectManagerId": "${managerId}"
  }`
};
```

(here the original column name is projectManager, and we are adding the Id in the end)

reference: [Update person or group field using REST API in Document Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174979/update-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api-in-document-library?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)