# Rest API Update Person Field (Multi user), Lookup Field(Multi lookup), Taxonomy Columns(Multi terms)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

how do i update complex fields like person/Group, Taxonomy, Lookup in rest api?

any code samples would definitely help me?

Comment: did you try this link pradeep, https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/using-rest-to-update-a-managed-metadata-column-in-sharepoint

Comment: for person and group you can get help from this link, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174979/update-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api-in-document-library

Answer (score 1):

**Update User field("UserField")**

Multiple user field value:

```
var item = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' },
    'UserFieldId' : { 'results': [10,11] }
};
```

Single user field value:

```
var item = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' },
    'UserFieldId' : 10
};
```

**Update Lookup field("LookupField")**

```
var item = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' },
    'LookupFieldId' : 1
};
```

**Update Managed Metadata field("MyTaxonomyField")**

```
var metaObject={
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue' },
    'Label':'<YOUR LABEL>',
    'TermGuid':'<YOUR TERM GUID>',
    'WssId': -1
}
var item = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' },  
    'MyTaxonomyField' : metaObject
};
```